# Recognizing when the UITableViewCell delete button is shown

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

I have the following problem:

My UITableViewCell contains an UIButton and if the user swipes from right to left to show the deletion button the button in the Cell gets triggered sometimes.

Is there a way to recognize the swipe or that the deletion button is shown, so I could avoid that the buttons event gets triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I check in the buttons event whether the tableview is currently in editing mode. This solved the problem :)